# Why would MikTeX ask for the Noto Inscriptionial Parthian Font?

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update

Any long term user of TeX is used to getting weird and or sometimes humorous messages.

I updated my installation today, and tried to test it by `texdoc source3`. I got the weird message:

qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to enumerate family "Noto Sans Inscriptional Parthian"

After updating the manual it printed OK, all 1532 pages of it and obviously never used the font.

I take it, since the Inscriptional Parthian, is part of unicode, this is for some interface that was build using **qt**. Scratching my head and I am curious to find out if anyone knows why I got this error message?

[image]